# Illegal Offset of an Array on Production Site

Tags: php

I'm getting the following warning message:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in
>   /home/bmtuser/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/plugin_file.php
>   on line 238

The offending line is the following code:

```
$new_sorted_array[$sort_order] = $term->term_id;
```

Here is the code before it to set that:

```
$new_sorted_array = array( );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $taxonomy_id = 'taxonomy_'.$term->term_id;
    $sort_order = get_option( $taxonomy_id, $term );
    $new_sorted_array[$sort_order] = $term->term_id;
}
ksort( $new_sorted_array, SORT_NUMERIC );
```

This works fine on my localhost but when I moved it to production it's give me this error. Why would that be the case?

Comment: seems like `get_option` might be returning false? is the sql database identical?

Answer (score 1):

`$sort_order` cannot be an index of `$new_sorted_array`. Mostly because it is not a number, neither a string.

Maybe your error displaying is lower on your machine. Include this at the top of your code for maximum error reporting: `error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that you're using for index variable of type object. It probably means that always or in some cases $term->term_id is not integer but object.
Firs you have to check the case and in case it is normal situation then you can avoid it by next addition:

```
<?php
$new_sorted_array = array( );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $xxx=$term->term_id;
    if(gettype($xxx)=='object') continue;
    $taxonomy_id = 'taxonomy_'.$xxx;
    $sort_order = get_option( $taxonomy_id, $term );
    $new_sorted_array[$sort_order] = $term->term_id;
}
ksort( $new_sorted_array, SORT_NUMERIC );

?>
```

In this way you'll avoid bad indexes.
I'm not agree that warning has to be suppressed - they has to be resolved.